# searching with relationship in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, search, relationship

i have a Category model, and product model, and there is a relationship between them... so now i want to make a serch, when the user write the name of category, i need to return all products inside this category, the tables and relationship are correct.... i tried this way, but didn't work:

where ($q) is the input text name:-

```
 $catSearches = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($q){
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$q.'%');
    })
        ->with(['products' => function($query) use ($q){
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$q.'%');
        }])->get();
```

and also tried this way, and same problem:

```
$catSearches = Category::with('products')->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%" )->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second format is the correct one, but without the `{}`

```
$catSearches = Category::with('products')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%' )->get();
```

If you need the products only (without the category)

```
$products = Products::whereHas('category', function($categoryQuery) use ($q){
    $categoryQuery->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$q.'%' );
})->get();
```

Comment: it is just show me the information for category that i search for it name?

Comment: @OsamaMohammed and it has the products in the attribute "products". If you only want the product, use the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to return products and not inside category, you will need to go other way.

```
$products = Product::whereHas('category', function ($q) use ($search) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
})->get();
```

It will return all products matching category name.